# vue.js push gives TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a something like this:

```
new Vue({    
    el: '#core',
    data: {
        checkedThemes: []
        ...
    }
})
```

and after:

```
mounted() {
    ...
    var theme = parseInt(parameters['theme']);
    this.checkedThemes.push(theme);
    ...
}
```

Calling the push raise a **TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined** but when I do it from the web page (adding some values) it works.

EDIT: this error is in Chrome. In firefox i get: **[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: themes[checkedTheme] is undefined"**

Moreover the array is well filled after the push.

[image: indicateur.js line 157 is the push]

Where does this error come from?

Comment: check your log clearly it will point you to to where it is originating from

Comment: The push call and next it goes in some vue.js internal code

Comment: well you need to share at least a screenshot of the log because I don't see `name` from your code

Comment: First, I don't see `checkedThemes` in your `data()`, next, where is `parameters` coming from?

Comment: Also, your error in Chrome is pretty specific: `themes[checkedTheme] is undefined`

Comment: theme is checkedThemes in data, i correct this. Parameters is just a dict. I can write var theme=42 if you prefere

Comment: @Derek yes i get sometinh in the html part. I will check that. TY

Answer (score 0):

Debug with Firefox was a better idea as it said: 
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: themes[checkedTheme] is undefined"

And the error was in the html (render) part.